# Flip the values in a pipeline chart

Tags: charts

I have a bucketed field in report, by which records are grouped and displayed on a pipeline chart. Half of the field values are bucketed in one bucket, the rest are Other (as otherwise blank cannot be bucketed).

As of now, the chart looks like this:

[image]

However, there is a requirement that the blue "Complete" values would appear in the bottom. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your report definition, click on the arrow next to your bucket grouping, click 'sort group by'-> [bucketname] -> ascending/descending

See this screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Wow thanks. I was nearly sure this is impossible, but you found it!

Comment: Glad to be of help :-)

Comment: this guy is a good guy